# How to make useRouteMatch work with types from react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm getting the match from my route using the hook like this

```
const match = useRouteMatch('/chat/:id');
```

and then I want to pass it down to child component. But when I'm passing it down I'm getting this error

```
Type 'match<{}> | null' is not assignable to type 'match<MatchParams>'.
```

In m child component I'm doing this

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface MatchParams {
  id: string;
}

interface ChildProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {}

const Child = ({ match }: ChildProps ): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{match}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Child ;
```

Could someone help me figure out how to type all if this properly please?

Comment: What is the type of `match` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the return value of `useRouteMatch` hook, it can be either of type

`match<{}> | null`.

`useRouteMatch` returns null, if the path that you have provided does not match. When you pass it down to the child component, you are sure that it is the correct match but TS is not sure as there was not a check to test for falsey values before passing it down.

The return is of type `match` and not `RouteComponentProps`.
`match` is a generic which is empty object by default and this is where the params you expect will go in. To make TS aware you will have to pass this in.

This is how you would have to type it.

*Parent.tsx*

```
export interface MatchParams {
  id: string;
}

const match = useRouteMatch<MatchParams>('/chat/:id');

return <Child match={match} />
```

**Child.tsx**

```
import { match } from 'react-router';
import { MatchParams } from './Parent';

interface ChildProps {
  match: match<MatchParams> | null
}

const Child = ({ match }: ChildProps ): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{match}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Child ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the whole point of `useRouteMatch` hook was to avoid passing around `match` as props.

In case you want to get the `match` or one of its inner properties (like params) you can use this hook directly in your child.

```
interface MatchParams {
  id: string;
}

const Child = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const match = useRouteMatch<MatchParams>();

  return (
    <>
      <div>{match}</div>
      <div>{match.params.id}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```